# what is the purpose of this(1) & this(2) in the following program?

Tags: java, methods, this

in the following program i have use the this(1) & this(2) what is the purpose of using this(1) & this(2) and i also want to know is this is a keyword or method?I am new to java programming language.

```
class Const
{
    Const()
    {
        this(1);
        System.out.println(1);

    }
    Const(int x)
    {
        System.out.println(2);
    }
}
class const1 extends Const
{
    int a;
    const1()
    {
        this(8);
        System.out.println(3);

    }
        const1(int x)
    {

        System.out.println(4);

    }
    public static void main(String s[])
    {
        new const1();
    }
}
```

Comment: You ever read "The Cat in the Hat"?  (Sorry, couldn't resist!)

Answer (score 5):

These are [alternate constructor invocations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7.1). They invoke another constructor in the same class. This allows multiple constructors to share the same code for common behavior.  Without it, you'd sometimes be forced to repeat yourself.

For example:

```
Const()
{
    this(1);
    ...
}
```

Calls this constructor with the actual argument "1":

```
Const(int x) { ... }
```

You can use the keyword `super()` in a similar way to invoke a superclass constructor.

From the Java Language Specification, [8.8.7.1, Explicit constructor invocations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7.1):

> Explicit constructor invocation statements can be divided into two kinds:
>
> Alternate constructor invocations begin with the keyword this (possibly prefaced with explicit type arguments). They are used to invoke an alternate constructor of the same class.
>
> Superclass constructor invocations begin with either the keyword super (possibly prefaced with explicit type arguments) or a Primary expression. They are used to invoke a constructor of the direct superclass.

Answer (score 1):

`this()` if used inside a constructor is actually used to invoke another constructor of the same class. It is particularly useful if you keep overloaded constructors .

```
public class Rectangle {
  private int x, y;
  private int width, height;

  public Rectangle() {
     this(0, 0, 0, 0);
  }
  public Rectangle(int width, int height) {
      this(0, 0, width, height);
  }
  public Rectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.width = width;
      this.height = height;
  }
...
}
```

**Remember,** `this()` or `super()` has to be the first statement in the constructor , if you use them . Hence they cannot be used together inside a constructor.

`this` if used inside a method body will refer to the current instance on which the method was invoked.

Read the Oracle tutorial for [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) and [super](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html).

Answer (score 0):

Its similar to creating overloads to methods so they emulate having 'optional' parameters such as this:

```
DoStuff(int x, int y)
{
    //Stuff
}

DoStuff(int x)
{
    DoStuff(x, x);
}
```

Except you are doing it in the constructor (if they don't pass a value just use the value 1).  To answer the question `this` invokes the constructor of the object.